# How to connect correct link directory files

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, redirect

I wanted to do is connect some files in different folder inside elogFiles folder. My problem is i dont know how to connect the files inside of another folder files.

here is the family tree of my files:

http://s38.photobucket.com/user/eloginko/media/folder_zpsa156e2a5.png.html

[image]

My problem the links is not correct.

Both code are not related. And the user.php is asking for connection from inside the dbc folder database.php and myScript.js wants to find user.php where is located inside the view folder.

myScript.js: " `url: 'js/../view/user.php',`"

user.php:  "`include_once('view/../dbc/database.php');`"

can anyone help me correct the correct directory links.

user.php

```
<?php
include_once('../dbc/database.php');

$db = new Connection();
$db = $db->dbConnect();

$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

    if(!empty($email) && !empty($pass)){
        $st = $db->prepare("SELECT * from user WHERE email=? AND password=?");
        $st->bindParam(1, $email);
        $st->bindParam(2, $pass);
        $st->execute();

        if($st->rowCount() == 1){
            echo "1";
            exit;
        } else {
            echo "Incorrect Email or Password";
        }
    }else{
        echo "Please enter Email and Password";
    }  
?>
```

myScript.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('div#show:empty').hide();
    $('#login').click(function(){

        var email = $('#lemail').val();
        var password = $('#lpassword').val();   

        $.ajax({
            data: {
             email : email, password : password
            },
            type: "POST",
            url: 'js/../view/user.php',
            success: function(data)
            {
               if (Number(data) == 1)
                    {           
                $(".show-page[data-page=progBar]").trigger("click");
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                    }
                else
                    {
                  $('div#show:empty').show();
                  $('#show').html(data);
                    }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

As your hierarchy is presently, provided, if you are on your `http://localhost/elogFiles/view/user.php`, you just need to go level one up `../`

**user.php**

```
<?php
include_once('../dbc/database.php');

$db = new Connection();
$db = $db->dbConnect();

$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

$response['status'] = '';
$response['message'] = '';

    if(!empty($email) && !empty($pass)){
        $st = $db->prepare("SELECT * from user WHERE email=? AND password=?");
        $st->bindParam(1, $email);
        $st->bindParam(2, $pass);
        $st->execute();

        if($st->rowCount() == 1){
            $response['status'] = 'OK';
        } else {
            $response['status'] = 'ERROR';
            $response['message'] = 'Username/Password not found';
        }
    }else {
        $response['status'] = 'ERROR';
        $response['message'] = 'Please input username/password';
    } 

    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
?>
```

Since, user.php processes the AJAX request, point the AJAX url attribute to this file. Consider this example:

**myScript.js**

```
$.ajax({
        data: {
            email : email, password : password
        },
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://localhost/elogFiles/view/user.php',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.status == 'OK') {           
                $(".show-page[data-page=progBar]").trigger("click");
                $('#myModal').modal('hide');
           } else {
                $('div#show:empty').show();
                $('#show').html(data.message);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: still failed to load the resources.

Comment: i want to do with the php is connect to the database on the dbc folder. And in the myScript i want to connect to the user.php on the view folder

Comment: no the script and the php are in the different folder

Comment: the php is in the user.php folder and the script is in the js folder

Comment: i posted the complete code in the question take a look

Comment: @user3718488 yes i saw now the currently edited question

Comment: @user3718488 still the ajax cant find th user.php...it says "failed to load to load the resources in the console

Comment: i just need to locate the correct directory cause my code is working fine if the files is in the same folder.

Comment: myScript.js is in the js folder and user.php is in the view folder.

Comment: @user3718488 in the url attribute you can explicitly put the full http path. check the edit. `http://localhost/elogFiles/view/user.php`, provided, your base domain is `localhost`

Comment: @user3718488 this can be different if your are using a virtual host

Comment: dude we didnt understand each other. Both files are not related. And the user.php is asking for connection from inside the dbc folder database.php and myScript.js wants to find user.php where is located inside the view folder.